# Can I use color literals in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uicolor, xcode11, nscolor

I want to use my color assets from the assets catalog using color literals.
In `UIKit`, we can directly use color literal is there any way to use color literals in SwiftUI

I have searched from Color initializer with `UIColor` parameter but none found

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Note:** From Xcode 11 Beta 5, `Color` has an initializer for this **already** and no need to implement it.

So you can use colorLiteral like this:

```
Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
```

[image: preview]

Or any other `CGColor`, `UIColor` (or `NSColor` for macOS):

```
Color(.red)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing i end up using named colors

Answer (score 17):

## Easy Drag and Drop Color for Xcode Swift UI

I find it helpful when designing layouts where I need to find and adjust a color quickly to use this method.

I do this whenever I want to use the drag and drop style color literals in SwiftUI.

Later, I can go back and add the hard coded color to my color scheme simply by commenting out "//" the color literal line in my code which reveals the RGB for my selected color.

[image: Using Easy Drag and Drop Color Literals with Xcode, Swift, SwiftUI]

---

- Sorry I couldn't find any other way to describe this answer except for posting it this format *

Hope that helps.

---

## **UPDATE: As of Xcode 13.2.1**

*Quite possibly it came out earlier but I didn’t catch it.*

To get the autocomplete to work, type this line into your code.

```
#colorLiteral()
```

Then the code will automatically place the literal in the code for you to make the selection.

---

Comment: Better than everything.

Comment: I have the same issue on Xcode 14.1(14B47b) The workaround on the "Updated" section helped. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `Color` defined in Asset Catalog by passing the string name inside the `init`.

So, if I have the "Background" color inside my `Assets.xcassets`:

[image]

I will use:

```
let backgroundColor = Color("Background")
```

Alternatively if the color is defined in another `Bundle` you can use:

```
Color(name: String, bundle: Bundle)
```

P.S. It's seem that Color Literals doesn't work with the Asset color's

Answer (score 3):

You actually can use this hidden protocol to afford the same use of color literals for `Color` as is available for `UIColor`:

```swift
extension Color: _ExpressibleByColorLiteral {
    public init(_colorLiteralRed red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float) {
        self = Color(.sRGB, red: Double(red), green: Double(green), blue: Double(blue), opacity: Double(alpha))
    }
}
```

Now you can use color literals for `Color` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SwiftUI has color literal.
The color literal is a parameter of the color struct. Use the following steps:
1. Type the word, `Colo`
2. Select Color literal from autocomplete[image]
3. Now you can click on the color literal and select a color[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 13.4 to use Color Literal:
Start typing:
let myColor = Color(#colorLiteral(

and an icon will appear.  Double click on the icon and the color selection box will appear.  After selecting the color be sure to use a closing parentheses after the color.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getRed() method of UIColor to get the red, green, blue and alpha components and then use them to create a Color object. You could even create an extension that did it for you.